# TypeScript or CoffeeScript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, typescript

Started using node.js for building web apps.

One of my colleague asked about TypeScript which is a new Language from Microsoft.
We have a plan to start our new Web app with node.js and TypeScript as a Scripting engine.

I just want to know is it right time to develop apps using TypeScript?
How about the future of TypeScript?

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/interviews/should-you-learn-coffeescript/

Comment: It's from Microsoft. There's your answer to the future of TypeScript :)

Answer (score 32):

Both TypeScript and CoffeeScript have their own strengths. But if you want to build a big application I'd recommend going with CoffeeScript as you end up writing less code. [Here's a nice slideshow](http://prezi.com/zkhsz49ownaw/coffeescript-vs-typescript/) that compares both TypeScript and CoffeeScript. This may be off topic but the development of TypeScript is clear at least part of MS is really serious about open source.

- TypeScript is under the Apache 2.0 license
- Source is available via git on Codeplex
- Installation is as easy as npm install -g typescript

Comment: I do not agree when saying CoffeScript is good for big application, using a typed language for big application is a big plus to catch bugs at compilation time. For this, reason, I think TypeScript is a good choice over coffescript when doing a large apps.

Answer (score 9):

TypeScript will be supported by all browsers. You can say its just another javascript. What I found TypeScript was easy to code and evern more easy to debug. Microsoft is in no mood to challenge the old JavaScript like they did by releasing Silverlight to challenge Flash.

Anytime you feel that u want to switch back to old JavaScript and don't want to use TypeScript its even more easy to convert your ts to Js.

[Try this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/) and see the difference between js and ts.

Comment: Based on the title, the question was about the differences between TypeScript and CoffeeScript, not between TypeScript and JavaScript.